# Unable to load DLL 'foo.dll', but only when running through vhost

Tags: visual-studio, dll, vshost.exe

This is a variation on the old

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'foo.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).
```

problem (where, of course, `foo.dll` is the name of an actual DLL). The strange part is that I only get this error when I "Run" in VS (2008 if that's relevant). That sits in the `MyApp.vhost.exe` processes.

If I run the actual app in a command line (`MyApp.exe`) I encounter no errors. The problem extends to unit tests with MSTest.

A check on the DLL with DependencyWalker on `Foo.dll` doesn't show any issues.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the DLL is in the folder where your EXE is.

Comment: It's there, in the output folder.